# How to sum value from one table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

am new to PHP. my question is i have a table with values and i want to sum the values of one of the column but its not working pls i would appreciate if you can help me with this

```
mysql_select_db($database_ebsConn, $ebsConn);
    $transact4 = "SELECT sum(credit) FROM account WHERE integral_no ='$intergra'";
    $transact5 = mysql_query($transact4, $ebsConn) or die(mysql_error());
    $transact6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($transact5);
```

pls i am waiting for your reply

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Sorry for being offtopic, but from where do you have that snippet? I've already seen it several times here.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool.

Comment: And explain what you mean by "not working". Are you seeing error messages? Is it returning an invalid result?

Comment: @ComFreek The cool kids visit the [PHP chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) to stay up to date :)

Comment: @ComFreek I got lazy and created a bookmarklet that simply opens up a comment box on the OP and pastes this (I have to click "Add comment" to make sure that I don't accidentally paste it without meaning to). I've uploaded the bookmarklet/javascript code here: http://pastebin.com/V6Z8iXqM

Comment: @ComFreek something more cool http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: thanks i really appreciate, now i have sum it up but the problem i have now is how will i subtract the values from each other note that the values are given in array format

Answer (score 0):

try to go with prepared Statements.... at least use separate database file

```
$sqlSEND=mysql_query("SELECT sum(credit) FROM account WHERE integral_no ='$intergra'");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlSEND)){
echo $result['sum(credit)'];
}
```

Comment: thanks i really appreciate, now i have sum it up but the problem i have now is how will i subtract the values from each other note that the values are given in array format

Comment: use a for loop to get the data of an array. then you can subtract. if you get the answer for your posted problem, accept it for future purposes. Thanks.